# Core Animation:Failed to allocate bytes. using core-plot on iPad

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-plot

im new to iphone developing so please teach me on stuff that i may miss out. 
so basically i have graphview.m which creates a coreplotviewcontroller.view in this way

```
    CorePlotViewController *aCorePlotViewController = [[CorePlotViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CorePlotViewController" bundle:nil];
aCorePlotViewController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,896,605);
aCorePlotViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(576, 374.5);
[aCorePlotViewController.view setTag:99];

[self.view addSubview:aCorePlotViewController.view];
```

i have a button in graphview.m which will sort of refresh the Coreplotview in this way

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:99]removeFromSuperview];

CorePlotViewController *aCPView = [[CorePlotViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CorePlotViewController" bundle:nil];
aCPView.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,896,605);
aCPView.view.center = CGPointMake(576, 374.5);
[aCPView.view setTag:99];
[self.view addSubview:aCPView.view];
```

in the simulator it works fine, the coreplot view which has a graph is being refreshed. but on the iPad , after refreshing for awhile, i get an error which is logged like this

CoreAnimation:failed to allocate 2168448 bytes.

So  im thinking maybe the memory that was allocated to it was not released?(i don't know).

Here are my CorePlotViewController.h and .m files.

CorePlotViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
#import "GraphView.h"

@interface CorePlotViewController : UIViewController <CPPlotDataSource>

{
CPXYGraph *graph;

NSMutableArray *dataForPlot;
NSMutableArray *dataForPlot2;

NSMutableArray *finalDatas;

NSMutableArray *numofdata;
NSMutableArray *numofdata2;
}

@property(readwrite, retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataForPlot;
@property(readwrite, retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataForPlot2;
@property(readwrite, retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *finalDatas;

@property(readwrite, retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *numofdata;
@property(readwrite, retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *numofdata2;

@end
```

CorePlotViewController.m

```
  #import "MedicalBedAppDelegate.h"
#import "CorePlotViewController.h"

#import "UsageData.h"
#import "GraphView.h"

@implementation CorePlotViewController

@synthesize dataForPlot;
@synthesize dataForPlot2;
@synthesize finalDatas;
@synthesize numofdata,numofdata2;

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot{

    MedicalBedAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MedicalBedAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"4 Hours") {
        return appDelegate.usagedatas.count;
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"1 Hour") {
        return appDelegate.usagedatas.count;
    }

    else if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"8 Minutes")
    {
        return appDelegate.usagedatas.count;
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"1 Minute") {
        return appDelegate.usagedatas.count;
    }   

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];


 MedicalBedAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MedicalBedAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
    self.view = [[CPLayerHostingView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds]; 
    CPLayerHostingView *hostingView = (CPLayerHostingView *)self.view;
    hostingView.hostedLayer = graph;
    graph.paddingLeft = 0.0;
    graph.paddingTop = 0.0;
    graph.paddingRight = 0.0;
    graph.paddingBottom = 0.0;

    //This applies the 'background color to the graph available themes are 
    //kCPDarkGradientTheme,kCPPlainWhiteTheme,KCPPlainBlackTheme,kCPStocksTheme,kCPSlateTheme
    CPTheme *Theme =[CPTheme themeNamed:kCPSlateTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:Theme];


    CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-0.015) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(14.2)];
    //plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-0.5) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(14.4)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-0.015) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(19.85)];
    //plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-1) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(19.85)];

    CPLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blackColor];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 0.0f;


    CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1"] decimalValue];
    //axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromFloat(1.0);
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 9;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 10.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 5.0f;
    //axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLocations = 2;


    axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1"] decimalValue];
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 9;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 0.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 0.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset = 5.0f;


    //Alloc and init a Scatter plot
    CPScatterPlot *breathRatePlot = [[CPScatterPlot alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 200, 25)] ;
    breathRatePlot.identifier = @"Breath Rate Plot";
    breathRatePlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 3.3f;
    breathRatePlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor yellowColor];
    breathRatePlot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:breathRatePlot];
    //Add Plot symbols to the points
    CPPlotSymbol *greenCirclePlotSymbol = [CPPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    greenCirclePlotSymbol.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:[CPColor greenColor]];
    greenCirclePlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(1.0 , 1.0);
    breathRatePlot.plotSymbol = greenCirclePlotSymbol;


    //Alloc and init a Scatter plot
    CPScatterPlot *noOfMovementRegisteredPlot = [[CPScatterPlot alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 12, 200, 25)];
    noOfMovementRegisteredPlot.identifier = @"Move Registered Plot";
    noOfMovementRegisteredPlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.3f;
    noOfMovementRegisteredPlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor redColor];
    noOfMovementRegisteredPlot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:noOfMovementRegisteredPlot];
    //Add Plot symbols to the points
    CPPlotSymbol *greenCirclePlotSymbol2 = [CPPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    greenCirclePlotSymbol2.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:[CPColor greenColor]];
    greenCirclePlotSymbol2.size = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
    noOfMovementRegisteredPlot.plotSymbol = greenCirclePlotSymbol2;



    //Get an instance of the appDelegate and set some vars to be used
    NSInteger indexPRowArrayInteger;
    NSString *indexPRowArrayString;
    indexPRowArrayString = [appDelegate.indexPathRowArray objectAtIndex:0 ] ;
    indexPRowArrayInteger = [indexPRowArrayString integerValue ];

    // Add some initial data
    NSMutableArray *contentArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *contentArray2 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSNumber *BRNumber;
    NSString *BRString;
    NSNumber *NOMRNumber;
    NSString *NOMRString;
    NSString *DString;


    NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    //Datetime section
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-4*60*60];//time from 4 hrs ago
    NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];
    NSDate *cDate1 = [timeFormat dateFromString:theTime];

    NSDate *now1Hr = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-1*60*60];//time from 1hr  ago
    NSString *theTime1Hr = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now1Hr];
    NSDate *cDate1Hr = [timeFormat dateFromString:theTime1Hr];

    NSDate *now8Mins = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-8*60];//time from 8Mins ago
    NSString *theTime8Mins = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now8Mins];
    NSDate *cDate8Mins = [timeFormat dateFromString:theTime8Mins];

    NSDate *now1Min = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-1*60];//time from 1Min ago
    NSString *theTime1Min = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now1Min];
    NSDate *cDate1Min = [timeFormat dateFromString:theTime1Min];

    NSUInteger i;
    NSUInteger i2;
    numofdata = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
numofdata2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for ( i = 0; i < appDelegate.usagedatas.count; i++ ) {
    //NSLog(@"appdelcount= %d",appDelegate.usagedatas.count);

    UsageData *aUsageDataInstance = (UsageData *)[appDelegate.usagedatas objectAtIndex:i];

    BRString = aUsageDataInstance.breathrate;
    BRNumber = [f numberFromString:BRString];

    DString = aUsageDataInstance.time;
    NSDate *cDate2 = [timeFormat dateFromString:DString];

    NSTimeInterval time = [cDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:cDate1];
    NSTimeInterval time1Hr = [cDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:cDate1Hr];
    NSTimeInterval time8Mins = [cDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:cDate8Mins];
    NSTimeInterval time1Min = [cDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:cDate1Min];

    if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"4 Hours") {
        id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: ((time/132)/9)];
        id y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([BRNumber intValue]/1.975) ];
        [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]];
    }


        //calculation = (time(interval from how many hrs/mins ago) / seconds of 1 minor-interval of x-axis(NOT MAJOR,1major has 10 minor intervals)/9
            //time = the number of seconds from the time in the database to the current time

        else if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"1 Hour") {
            id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((time1Hr/33.3)/9)];
            id y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([BRNumber intValue]/1.975) ];
            [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]];
        } 
        else if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"8 Minutes") {
            id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: ((time8Mins/4.4)/9)];
            id y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([BRNumber intValue]/1.975) ];
            [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]];
        }
        else if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"1 Minute") {
            id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: ((time1Min/0.53)/9)];
            id y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([BRNumber intValue]/1.975) ];
            [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]];
        }
    }
    self.dataForPlot = contentArray;



    for ( i2 = 0; i2 < appDelegate.usagedatas.count; i2++ ) {
        UsageData *aUsageDataInstance = (UsageData *)[appDelegate.usagedatas objectAtIndex:i2];

        NOMRString = aUsageDataInstance.noofmovereg;
        NOMRNumber = [f numberFromString:NOMRString];

        DString = aUsageDataInstance.time;      
        NSDate *cDate2 = [timeFormat dateFromString:DString];

        NSTimeInterval time = [cDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:cDate1];
        NSTimeInterval time1Hr = [cDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:cDate1Hr];
        NSTimeInterval time8Mins = [cDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:cDate8Mins];
        NSTimeInterval time1Min = [cDate2 timeIntervalSinceDate:cDate1Min];

        if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"4 Hours") {
        id x2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: ((time/132)/9)];
        id y2 = NOMRNumber;
        [contentArray2 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x2, @"x", y2, @"y", nil]];

        }
    else if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"1 Hour") {
            id x2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((time1Hr/33.3)/9)];
            id y2 = NOMRNumber;
            [contentArray2 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x2, @"x", y2, @"y", nil]];

        }
        else if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"8 Minutes") {
            id x2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: ((time8Mins/4.4)/9)];
            id y2 = NOMRNumber;
            [contentArray2 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x2, @"x", y2, @"y", nil]];

        }
        else if ([appDelegate.timetodisplay objectAtIndex:0] == @"1 Minute") {
            id x2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: ((time1Min/0.53)/9)];
            id y2 = NOMRNumber;
            [contentArray2 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x2, @"x", y2, @"y", nil]];
        }
    }
    self.dataForPlot2 = contentArray2;

    //release for memory management.
    [dateFormat release];
    [timeFormat release];
    [now release];
    [now1Hr release];
    [now8Mins release];
    [now1Min release];
    [f release];
    [noOfMovementRegisteredPlot release];
    [breathRatePlot release];

    [contentArray release];
    [contentArray2 release];

    }

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot 
                     field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum 
               recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
    NSNumber *num = [[dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")];
    NSNumber *num2 = [[dataForPlot2 objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")];

    if ([(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"Breath Rate Plot"])
    {
        if ( fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldY ) 
            num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue] ];
        return num;
    }
        else {
            num2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[num2 doubleValue] ];
        return num2;
    }


}
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft );
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)dealloc {


    [graph release];
    [dataForPlot release];
    [dataForPlot2 release];
    [finalDatas release];
    [numofdata release];
    [numofdata2 release];
    [super dealloc];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not releasing either of your CorePlotViewController instances, which over time will cause a problem.  After adding the VC's view as a subview you can release the controller, i.e. `[aCorePlotViewController release];`.  Then do the same for the refresh.

If that doesn't fix it, try doing a Build & Analyze to see if you're having memory issues elsewhere.

Comment: Did you do the Build and Analyze?  If you did and fixed everything, then the problem is elsewhere.  This is a memory problem, as that error only comes up when your app uses too much memory.

Comment: Would like to know if you got to the bottom of this? I'm experiencing similar problems with CoreText. My Build and Analyze is fine and Leaks doesn't show any leaks, so really confusing